# DLM implementation of the mean reverting model

Tags: kalman-filter, state-space-models, dlm

I am trying to use DLM package in R to estimate a state space repersentation of the term structure model, where observation and state equation are as follows

$y(t )= F* x_t  +e_t$
$x_t- \mu = G* (x_{t-1}-\mu) +n_t$

where $e_t$ and $n_t$ are Gaussian. Only modification with  standard DLM representation in the R  is the term $\mu$ (mean of the state variable) (which is also unknown)  in the state equation. I am not sure how to use DLM package to estimate such models.

I would be extremely grateful for the any help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your state equation can be writen as
$$\pmatrix{x_t \\ \mu_t} = \pmatrix{G & I-G \\ 0 & I}\pmatrix{x_{t-1} \\\mu_{t-1}}  + \pmatrix{n_t \\ 0}.$$
The extra element in the state vector will track after some iterations of the Kalman filter the fixed mean $\mu$.

Comment: thanks a lot Tusell ...I got the idea...but I think modification  should be $ \pmatrix{G & I-G \\ 0 & I}$ ....

Comment: Quite right, my bad. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to help me on this one as well ....https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322667/state-space-implementation-of-macro-finance-term-structure-model-observable-st